# Nested Media Object clearfix not working

Tags: css, oocss

Using the OOCSS media object from N. Sullivan. I modified the original css to remove overflow hidden and replace it with the micro-clearfix. The problem I'm running into is when I try to nest the media objects, the nested media object doesn't clear its float. I am trying to avoid overflow: hidden;

Take a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kDpLr

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Media Object</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="media">

          <a href="http://twitter.com/stubbornella" class="img">
            <img src="http://stubbornella.com/profile_image.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="me" />
          </a>

          <div class="bd">
            Here is some text inside the media object. Here is some text inside the media object.
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="media">

          <a href="http://twitter.com/stubbornella" class="img">
            <img src="http://stubbornella.com/profile_image.jpg" alt="me" height="200" width="200" />
          </a>

          <div class="bd">
            <h2>Headline</h2>
            <p>Here is some text inside the media object. Here is some text inside the media object. Here is some text inside the media object.</p>
            <div class="media">

                  <a href="http://twitter.com/stubbornella" class="img">
                    <img src="http://stubbornella.com/profile_image.jpg" alt="me" />
                  </a>

                  <div class="bd">
                    Here is some text inside the media object.
                  </div>

                </div>
          </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
/* ====== media ====== */
.media {
    margin:10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    @extend %clearfix;
}

.bd {
  @extend %clearfix;
}

.media .img {
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.media .img img {
    display:block;
}

.media .img-right {
    @extend %clearfix;
    float:right; 
    margin-left: 10px;
}

%clearfix {
    &:before,  
    &:after {  
        content: " ";  
        display: table;  
    }  
    &:after {  
        clear: both;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not clearing the float properly - using the clearfix only ensures that `.media` element extends as far as its floated children elements go, therefore working the same as `overflow: hidden`.

All you need is to add `clear: both` to the `.media` selector itself (not to the pseudo :before or :after elements), and then you'll fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had better luck floating the 'bd' class.